# How to set the number of fermions in the whole system in fermionic-DMRG program?

Tags: condensed-matter, renormalization, computational-physics, simulations, fermions

In infinite DMRG (density matrix re-normalization group) algorithm, we increase size of super-block by two sites in each iteration. How do we set number of fermions in the system? Let's say we want to study a system at quarter filling i.e. $n = L/N = 1/2$ where $L = $ number of sites with degree of freedom $4$ and $N = $ number of fermions.

In $i$-th iteration, we have $2(i+2)$ sites in system. How do we set number of particles in system for $i$-th iteration?